# General way to convert String into Big Decimal

Tags: java, numbers, decimal, number-formatting, bigdecimal

In my Java code I have four number in text format (String):
Es.

```
String s1 = "1234.56";
String s2 = "1235,56";
String s3 = "1,234.56";
String s4 = "1.234,56";
```

I want to convert these Strings into BigDecimal:

```
BigDecimal b1 = new BigDecimal(s1);
...
...
```

Obviously it does not work, because BigDecimal does not accept all formats (strings with commas).
There is a general way that allows me to convert all strings in BigDecimal?

Answer (score 1):

Decimal part is allways locale dependent, so you can use the **NumberFormat** class and use the parsed result as string to get a BigDecimal from it

## Example:

```
final NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
final Number number = format.parse("3,1415");
final BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(number.toString());
System.out.println(bd);
```

Comment: Since `format.parse` [will return a Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-java.text.ParsePosition-), this will suffer from the same problem as the [BigDecimal(double) constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-): Inexact values that do not match the input string.

Comment: for string "s3" print 1.234

Comment: yes, and 1.234 is a valid input to Bigdecimal

Comment: But I want 1234.56 !

Answer (score 0):

What about  `DecimalFormat` ? [Doc here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

You just have to define a pattern for decimal separator before parsing the string...

```
 DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##");
 decimalFormat.setParseBigDecimal(true);
 BigDecimal bigDecimal = (BigDecimal) decimalFormat.parse("1,234.56");
 System.out.println(bigDecimal);
```

Should do the trick

Comment: Ok, but really I do not know the format of the "n" strings.
use case is: I have an array of strings and I have to convert .

Comment: If you don't have pattern you can't parse anything. How to make difference between "1,234.56" and  "1.234,56"  without pattern ?

Comment: If you know that there is always 2 decimals you can pick the decimal separator to build the pattern I think....

Comment: your code print 1.234

Answer (score 0):

To cover  all cases I would suggest following impl:

```
private static BigDecimal convertToBigDecimal(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if (s.indexOf('.') != -1 && s.indexOf(',') != -1) {
        s = s.replace(',', '.');
        String[] ss = s.split("\\.");
        for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0 && i == ss.length - 1) {
                sb.append('.');
            }
            sb.append(ss[i]);
        }
    } else if (s.indexOf('.') != -1) {
        String[] ss = s.split("\\.");
        if (ss.length > 2) {
            sb.append(s.replace(".", ""));
        } else {
            // assume it is decimal delimiter
            sb.append(ss[0]).append('.').append(ss[1]);
        }
    } else if (s.indexOf(',') != -1) {
        String[] ss = s.split(",");
        if (ss.length > 2) {
            sb.append(s.replace(",", ""));
        } else {
            // assume it is decimal delimiter
            sb.append(ss[0]).append('.').append(ss[1]);
        }
    }

    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(sb.toString());
    return bd;
}
```

The ideas is first check if  we have both than we definitely have decimal part and we replace all `,` to `.` and then skip all `.` except last one. Otherwise if we have several same delimiters it is number without decimal part. In other case we need to know pattern to distinguish with decimal or not. For sample numbers we assume it is with decimal.

Comment: For  "1,234,567" (no decimal part) the result will be wrong... (1234.567) But that's the best shot so far...

Comment: You are right @BenB. It is unreal to distinguish without know a pattern for case 111,222  whether it is 1112222 or 111.222.